# Changing units of variance to match changed mean

Tags: meta-analysis

I have a mean of hrs/day. I have converted this to mins/day (by multiplying by 60). However I am not sure what I should do with the SD or confidence intervals which refer to the variance of hrs/day.

How would I derive the SD and confidence intervals for mins/day?

Comment: $E[a \cdot X]=a \cdot E[X]$, $Var[a \cdot X]=a^2 \cdot Var[X]$.

Comment: I don’t know what this means. Could you clarify thisfurther please?

Comment: If you multiplied your values by 60 then you need to multiply your original variance (hrs/day) by $60^2$ to get the new variance (mins/day).

Comment: I might've misunderstood - Multiply by 60 squared for the variance? This created a huge number. Or just multiply by 60?

Comment: $60^2$ times the old variance.

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply the units by a factor $a$ then

You multiply the mean by $a$

You multiply the standard deviation y $a$ and by extension you multiply the limits of the confidence interval by $a$ too

You multiply the variance by $a^2$